# How to recreate same id object in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

We know `id` is incremented at the database level to maintain uniqueness but if accidentally any id is deleted then, we can not do anything with production environment?
can anyone help me to understand is there any way to create an object with the same id when we delete it.

```
eg:- user = User.find 1    
     user.destroy
```

Now if I found `User.find 1` will  give me an error, what I want to create the same user with same `id 1` ? is this possible as I was trying to find it but could not find yet

Comment: I don't think that is possible, the id is incremented at the database level to maintain uniqueness

Comment: Rails is auto-generated id. Question, why do you want to do that?

Comment: have you tried `User.create! id: 1, ...`?

Comment: @Phlip yes not working

Comment: @araratan some error into production due to id delete, which was assigned to too many places and due to not design database properly it did not delete all child data

Comment: @Subash I know it's not possible in the way rails work but there might be chances to do that which I am looking if possible

Comment: I think you should override the `id`. Check this tutorial I found: http://ruby-journal.com/how-to-override-default-primary-key-id-in-rails/

Comment: @araratan thanks, I know this but don't want to override it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually its not suggested todo, because ID is incremented at the database level to keep uniqueness.

You can assign the ID, all you need is make sure the same id is exist.

```
unless Store.find_by(id: 2)
   s = Store.new
   s.id = 2
   #make sure dnt have any validations
   s.save #
end
```

Probably, You have tried to use `.find(2)`.

It will return `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find User with 'id'=2`.

Use `.find_by_id(2)` or `.find_by(id: 2)` it will return boolean `true || false`